# What am I doing wrong to calculate this standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, radicals, standard-deviation, means, data-analysis

[This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49425/calculate-largest-possible-standard-deviation-for-a-set) mentions in passing that the standard deviation of the data set (1, 50) is about 34.65. Wolfram Alpha confirms this, saying it is $\frac{49}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 34.648$. But when I try to calculate this by hand, I get:

$\mu = \frac{1+50}{2}=\frac{51}{2}=25.5$

$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{(25.5-1)^2+(25.5-50)^2}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{(24.5)^2+(-24.5)^2}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot(24.5)^2}{2}}=24.5$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure the original question is what you think it means. But I don't know what it's about either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually did standard deviation correct, what you did is called the **population standard deviation.**

What the original problem was talking about and wolfram alpha said is called **sample standard deviation.**

Sample standard deviation is calculated with this formula: $s= \sqrt{\frac{\sum _{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-{\overline {x}})^{2}}{N-1}}$

Comment: Thank you for this answer!

Comment: @Rasputin no problem!

Answer (score 1):

If $(1,50)$ represents the population, you divide by $n=2$ in the calculation of standard deviation, but if it's a sample from the population (in this case, of size $2$), then you divide by $n-1=2-1$ in this case. The former refers to the population standard deviation and the latter the sample standard deviation.

$$s=\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot (24.5)^2}{2-1}}=34.65$$

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for this answer!